# How to use Id autoinkriment at Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

Probably a silly question but I don't get it.
So I've got a class like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="colour"
    ,catalog="car_store"
)
public class Colour  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Byte id;
     private String name;
     private Set<Car> cars = new HashSet<Car>(0);

    public Colour() {
    }


    public Colour(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Colour(String name, Set<Car> cars) {
       this.name = name;
       this.cars = cars;
    }

     @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)


    @Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    public Byte getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Byte id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    @Column(name="name", nullable=false)
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="colour")
    public Set<Car> getCars() {
        return this.cars;
    }

    public void setCars(Set<Car> cars) {
        this.cars = cars;
    }
}
```

So if I'm trying to insert like:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Colour newColour = new Colour();

newColour.setName("Deep Sea Blue");
session.save(newColour);

session.getTransaction().commit();
```

it should not automaticly generate new id value during this? Because it doesn't.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-identifier

Comment: I've see that and I suppose my mapping is right. I get and set all class's properties and etc, and if I even put annotations in front where class's properties declared, like in the example, It doesn't change anything at all, in other ways I’ve got everything just like in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-identifier) provided type of the property is Long. In the example provided by you Byte is used. I assume there can be problems with this. Try to change it to Long.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove

> @Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable=false)

from

> public Byte getId()

It looks redundant.
And leave only:

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)
public Byte getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
```

Comment: I agree, have removed that. However, new id unfortunately is still not generated.

Comment: Please also check [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Common_Problems_4).

Comment: Mysql database itself is configured right. When I do INSERT INTO colour (name) VALUES("Deep Sea Blue"); it work just fine. So if it's not my inserting code nor maping not database itself. What else could it be according to that article, Hibernate? I don't get it. Could you help me out?

Comment: Have you tried to change strategy to AUTO?
And also I see that in Hibernate documentation Long type is used whereas you are using Byte. I assume there can be problems with this. Try to change it to Long.

Comment: Oh my! Thanks a lot! I've changed type to Long at the mapping and there it is! Changing strategy to auto doesn't effect anyway. Please post the answer. Thanks again.